# Setting S3 directory for temporary files of delta tables spark session

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

When I try to create a Spark session and set the local dir in S3 (to avoid issues with executor memory). Spark still creates the temp files in my local disk.

This is the config I'm using:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("upsert_delta_table") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "50g") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "50g") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", aws_access_key_id) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", aws_secret_access_key) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4") \
    .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access', True) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .config("spark.local.dir", "s3a://datalake-silver.dummy/spark_logs/temp_files_for_calculations") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.buffer.dir", "s3a://datalake-silver.dummy/spark_logs/temp_files_for_calculations") \
    .config("spark.worker.cleanup.enabled", True) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

I'm able to mount, read and write delta tables using this notation for example (so is not a connectivity issue):

```
spark.sql(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {database}.{table_name} USING DELTA LOCATION 's3://datalake-silver.dummy/database/table_1'")
```

I ran the script from the terminal and I found this in the logs, but I don't know what to do:

```
/21 00:19:40 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/11/21 00:19:40 WARN SparkConf: Note that spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone/kubernetes and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).
23/11/21 00:19:41 WARN Utils: The configured local directories are not expected to be URIs; however, got suspicious values [s3a://datalake-silver.dummy/spark_logs/temp_files_for_calculations]. Please check your configured local directories.
23/11/21 00:19:43 WARN MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `spark.local.dir` is local to the host
2. s3 is not a real filesystem and cannot be used as a replacement
3. spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.buffer.dir MUST be local fs, as it is where blocks being written are buffered *before being uploaded to S3 storage*. Declaring it an s3 store makes no sense whatsoever.

You need more local storage, transient or in EBS.